# calculating average of a column in mysql database for windows form application

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, forms

I am trying to compute average of a column of my mysql database and save it in a variable so I can use it for further calculation such as finding variance for normal distribution. How ever, when I run my code, it's not showing me any error but it's not reading database either. I have added checkpoints in my code to see how far it is going. Program is showing me exception message "No database selected" before checkpoint 2. Any help would be appreciated.

```
decimal proteinAvg;

        string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root"
        string Query = "SELECT AVG(Protein) AS proteinAvg FROM nutritioncalculator";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;


try
{
   myConn.Open();
   //checkpoint1
   MessageBox.Show("connected");
   myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
   //Checkpoint2

   MessageBox.Show("connected");
   while (myReader.Read())
   {
      //checkpoint3
      MessageBox.Show("connected");
      proteinAvg = (decimal) myReader["proteinAvg"];
      MessageBox.Show("Your protein intake should be around" + proteinAvg);
   }
```

Comment: Your [connection string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html) is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying a database name in your `ConnectionString` object.

Try this:

```
string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;Database=mydatabase;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
```

Refere this Link for [MySQL Connection String](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: In `MySql` they don't use `Initial Catalog`, they use `Database`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code here, and I will highlight them in my answer.

```
decimal proteinAvg;
// MySql uses 'database' and not 'Initial Catalog' like Sql does.
string myConnection = string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;Database=mydatabase;port=3306;username=root;password=root";  // MySql uses 'database' to define the DB name.
string Query = "SELECT AVG(Protein) AS proteinAvg FROM nutritioncalculator";

// Wrap your connection and command objects in 'using' blocks.  
// Both implement IDisposable and will be managed by GC once 
// they fall out-of-scope. 
using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
{   
   using (MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn))
   {
      MySqlDataReader myReader;
      try
      {
         myConn.Open();
         //checkpoint1
         MessageBox.Show("connected");
         myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
         //Checkpoint2

         MessageBox.Show("connected");
         while (myReader.Read())
         {
            //Checkpoint3
            MessageBox.Show("connected");
            proteinAvg = (decimal) myReader["proteinAvg"];
            MessageBox.Show("Your protein intake should be around" + proteinAvg);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Brain - I tried doing it but than both cmdDatabase and myReader will fall out of scoup when using them in try catch block .

Comment: @YashPatel - Yes, that is correct.  Let me edit my answer and move the `try/catch`.